# Swimming with scuba diving egg?

Tags: swimming

I was using a 'waterproof' pouch bag to store my keys and documents while swimming. Well, it was waterproof until because of wear (after a few uses) I've got a small punctation in the edge, and everything was wet inside.

I don't want to damage my car keys, and my scuba diving friends have recommended me the scuba diving egg like this: [image] to be full water proof in the shallow waters.

The problem: how to use it while swimming? When I'm swimming with a swimming bag, it's not an issue, but then I don't need anything else to store my keys. But swimming shorter distance near to shore, I don't need a swimming bag, and this egg looks as an interesting alternative. But I have no idea how can I mount it so it doesn't be awkward while doing swimming strokes (a wrist would be quite a terrible choice, obviously).

Comment: Seems way too big to stuff in your swimsuit, as you say you don't want it on your wrist. Attach to a simple lightweight webbing belt around your waist?

Comment: @JonCuster nice idea

Comment: If they have one with a belt loop to hold it firmly (say on your back) that would be best. That loop of string looks like it might bounce around which might be irritating.

Answer (score 5):

The egg in your image seems to be 11.5 x 6 cm according to a google search. That should be small enough to not be a huge problem.

My suggestion would be to go with one of the following:

- Attach it to your bathing trunks - especially if you have surf shorts or some similar variant they often have a pocket with a little loop to attach keys or similar. Alternatively attach it to the strap used for tying up the shorts in the front.
- Wear it as a necklace around your neck. Note that due to buoyancy the egg will likely switch to your back and be dragged behind you while swimming - however, drag should be small enough to not be a huge issue, and it's a lot better than having it attached to your arms/legs which move through the water a lot more than your torso/neck does.

I have done both with similarly small keep-my-stuff-dry products, and it worked well enough.